# Grails hibernate create criteria multiple AND OR Conditions

Tags: hibernate, grails-orm, conditional-statements, createcriteria

I was able to do 3 conditions query using grails/Hibernate create Criteria as follows

```
 def c = Domain.createCriteria()

    c.list(max: map.max ?: 10, offset: map.offset ?: 0) {

            and {
                "colStatus" in status
                "code" in codes
            }
            and {
                or {
                    ilike("pCode", pCode)
                    ilike("pDesc", pCode)
                }
            }

        order("DateCol3", "desc")
    }
```

Now i have additional 3 add conditions with internal OR conditions which i need add upto the query. I tried following with no success

```
 def c = Domain.createCriteria()

    c.list(max: map.max ?: 10, offset: map.offset ?: 0) {

            and {
                "colStatus" in status
                "code" in codes
            }
            and {
                or {
                    ilike("pCode", pCode)
                    ilike("pDesc", pCode)
                }
            }

            and {
                or {
                    ilike("eCode", eCode)
                    ilike("eDesc", eCode)
                }
            }

            and {
                or {
                    ilike("oCode", oCode)
                    ilike("oDesc", oCode)
                }
            }

        order("DateCol3", "desc")
    }
```

Please suggest and help me how i should be adding up multiple AND/OR conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with introduction of parenthesis

```
def c = Domain.createCriteria()

c.list(max: map.max ?: 10, offset: map.offset ?: 0) {

        {
            "colStatus" in status
            "code" in codes
        }
        ( {
            or {
                ilike("pCode", pCode)
                ilike("pDesc", pCode)
            }
        }
      )
      (
       {
            or {
                ilike("eCode", eCode)
                ilike("eDesc", eCode)
            }
        }
      )
      (  and {
            or {
                ilike("oCode", oCode)
                ilike("oDesc", oCode)
            }
        }
      )
    order("DateCol3", "desc")
}
```